# SEM: Why is there no dependable connection between the size of SEM residuals and the type or degree of model misspecification?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, misspecification

Kline (2016) p. 278 writes

> [Y]ou should know that there is actually no dependable or trustworthy
> connection between the size of the residuals and the type or degree of
> model misspecification. For example, the degree of misspecification
> indicated by a low correlation residual may be slight and yet may be
> severe.
>
> One reason is that values of residuals and other diagnostic
> statistics, including modification indexes (described later), are
> themselves affected by misspecification. An analogy in medicine would
> be a diagnostic test for some disease that is less accurate in
> patients who actually have that disease. This problem in SEM is a
> consequence of error propagation when some parts of the model are
> incorrectly specified. This problem may be even greater when the
> estimation method is simultaneous (e.g., ML) rather than single
> equation (e.g., 2SLS). But we do not generally know in advance which
> parts of the model are incorrect, so it can be difficult to understand
> exactly what the residuals are telling us.

I understand that “one reason” Kline gives, but it seems like Kline doesn’t then give any other reasons. Are there any other reasons, or is that it?

Kline, R. B. (2016). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling. Guilford publications.

Comment: I will try to write a full answer to this, but the easiest way to see this is to play around with some population models - take, e.g. a cfa model population covariance matrix with two correlated factors, and fit a single factor model to it. Your model is misspecified, but the fit won't be awful, and the loadings will change to make up for it.